# Scrollable MapView inside of a RecyclerView: dispatchTouchEvent vs onTouchEvent

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to have a scrolling MapView inside of a RecyclerView, therefore I'm setting `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` before and after the TouchEvent.

The odd thing is: this does work if I set it in the `dispatchTouchEvent()` method, but it doesn't work if I do the same in the `onTouchEvent()` method.

Can somebody explain why I cannot set this in `onTouchEvent()`?

Working:

```java
public class WorkingScrollableListItemMapView extends MapView {

    // constructors

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Stop parents from handling the touch
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow parents from handling the touch
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Not working:

```java
public class NotWorkingScrollableListItemMapView extends MapView {

    // constructors

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow parents from handling the touch
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Stop parents from handling the touch
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what does "not working" mean? Does it mean, that the parent `ViewGroup` still intercepts this event?

Comment: Yes, so a horizontal scroll would still kind of work (but sluggishly), but a vertical scroll wouldn't at all.

Answer (score 1):

Call sequence for handling an event are somewhat in this order:
onInterceptTouchEvent, onDispatchTouchEvent, dispatchTouchEvent,  onTouchEvent.
That, to me, indicates that the onTouchEvent is the very last step in processing an event. It would be too late to manipulate where & whom handles the event at the very last step. What does the source code say if you look at the earlier methods for handling the event?

Comment: Indeed, onTouchEvent is called last. But as far as I understand it's the dispatchTouchEvent() method that calls through to the onTouchEvent() so somewhere in the beginning of the dispatchMethod() the event gets lost. But I fail to understand why that is...