# Moving mapview inside recyclerview calling onLongClick

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mapview

i have a mapview inside a recyclerview, but i am having a problem trying to make the events inside the mapview be handled by the map itself and not the recyclerviewer. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608941/scrollable-mapview-inside-of-a-recyclerview-dispatchtouchevent-vs-ontouchevent)  which showed me that i should override the dispatchTouchEvent method with  getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true).
Well, it indeed makes the map answer to the touch event, but somehow any touch in the map trigger a OnLongClick on the parent RecyclerView and i just can not understand why/how. This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private int currentSelected =-1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        rv = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        LatLng eifel = new LatLng(48.858093, 2.294694);
        LatLng liberty = new LatLng(40.689247, -74.044502);
        LatLng vatican = new LatLng(41.906487, 12.453641);

        ArrayList<LatLng> l = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        l.add(eifel); l.add(liberty) ; l.add(vatican);
        rv.setAdapter(new Adapter(l));

        rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemListener(getApplicationContext(), rv, new RecyclerItemListener.RecyclerTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {
                    }

                    public void onLongClickItem(final View v, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onLongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (currentSelected == position)
                            destroyMap(position);
                        else
                            prepareMaps(position);
                    }
                })
        );


    }

    public void prepareMaps(final int position) {
        final Adapter.MyViewHolder holder  =  ( Adapter.MyViewHolder)rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        final LatLng selected = ((Adapter)rv.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
        if (!holder.mapsCreated) {
            holder.mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    LatLng place = new LatLng(selected.latitude, selected.longitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title("Marker"));
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(place)
                            .zoom(16)
                            .build();
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }

            });
            holder.mapView.onCreate(null);
            holder.mapView.onStart();
            holder.mapView.onResume();
            holder.mapsCreated = true;
        }
        else {
            holder.mapView.onResume();
        }
        currentSelected = position;
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void destroyMap(int position) {
        Adapter.MyViewHolder holder  =  ( Adapter.MyViewHolder)rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        holder.container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (holder.mapsCreated)
            holder.mapView.onPause();
        currentSelected = -1;
    }



    class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<LatLng> locations;

        class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView text;
            LinearLayout container;
            MapView mapView;
            boolean mapsCreated = false;

            MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                text = view.findViewById(R.id.latlng);
                container = view.findViewById(R.id.container);
                mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            }
        }


        public Adapter(ArrayList<LatLng> locations) {
            this.locations=locations;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.simple_row,parent, false);
            return new Adapter.MyViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            String lat = String.valueOf(locations.get(position).latitude);
            String lng = String.valueOf(locations.get(position).longitude);
            holder.text.setText("Location: \nLat: " + lat + "\nLong:" + lng+ "\n");


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return locations.size();
        }

        public LatLng getItem(int position) {
            return locations.get(position);
        }

    }
}

class RecyclerItemListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private RecyclerTouchListener listener;
    private GestureDetector gd;

    public interface RecyclerTouchListener {
        public void onClickItem(View v, int position) ;
        public void onLongClickItem(View v, int position);
    }

    public RecyclerItemListener(Context ctx, final RecyclerView rv, final RecyclerTouchListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        gd = new GestureDetector(ctx,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        View v = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        listener.onLongClickItem(v, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        View v = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                        listener.onClickItem(v, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
                        return true;
                    }

                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        return ( child != null && gd.onTouchEvent(e));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}




class CustomMapView extends MapView {

    public CustomMapView(Context context) {
        this(context,null);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

is anyone able to tell me why the onLongClick is being called when i try to move the map or click over the map ? It does not matter if it is just a single tap, the onLongClick is being called in the recyclerview.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
  rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemListener(getApplicationContext(), rv, new RecyclerItemListener.RecyclerTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {
                }

                public void onLongClickItem(final View v, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onLongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (currentSelected == position)
                        destroyMap(position);
                    else
                        prepareMaps(position);
                }
            })
    );
```

First you have set on touch listener to item of recyclerview so it always been call when you just touch the view and in side it you have set onLongClickItem method so i suggest you to put that method out side the touch listeners scope and if you want to perform operation on long press than set it on particular item view with proper onLonglClickListener

Comment: Thanks, jay! but i could not really understand what you meant. My problem is that moving the map inside the view is calling the on**Long**ClickItem method on the recycler view.<br/> if i add a toaster inside the on **onClickItem** just to debug purposes, it  is never called when i single tap over the map. So, the question is who is calling the on**Long**ClickItem